# Multiple social logins

Tags: hybridauth

I want to set up multiple social media logins on my site (using Hybridauth) but I'm not clear with the theory how should I handle the users.

For example if a user logs in with Google, changes/adds something on the site, then later logs in with the same email but with Facebook, should I handle separately this user or migrate his profile into one? How big sites implement this, what is the accepted method?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

You link multiple social login providers on email id base like
user login from facebook using abc@xyz.com email id
now user login from google using abc@xyz.com email id

then link both provider on email id base